# Flask: When uploading multiple files, list is empty

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to upload multiple files and save them in a specified folder for later use. When I use getlist on the input, the list is coming up empty.

I've tried

```
<input type="file" name="rename" multiple/> 
<input type="file" name="rename" webkitdirectory mozdirectory/>
<input type="file" name="rename" webkitdirectory multiple/> 


files = request.files.getlist("rename")
files = request.files.getlist("rename[]")
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method ="POST"> 

    <form action = "" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        <p>Upload files to be renamed.</p>
        <input type="file" name="rename" multiple/>  
        <input type = "submit" value="Upload">  <br><br>
    </form> 

</form>
```

Flask app:

```
import os
import os.path
from flask import render_template, redirect


# route for renaming a directory/group of files
@app.route('/renamesubmit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def rename2():
    path = './HARCresults/'
    renamepath = path + 'rename/'
    csvname = session.get('csv', "None")
    csv = path + csvname
    if not os.path.exists(renamepath):
        os.mkdir(renamepath)
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        files = request.files.getlist("rename")
        for f in files:
            f.save(os.path.join(renamepath, f.filename))
        #rename(renamepath, csv)
        return redirect('/results')
    else:
        return render_template('renamesubmit.html')
```

Comment: Do you see the files in f iterable?

Comment: No, looking now I see that the list is empty.